# Kendo menu z-index

Tags: c#, css, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to have the menu on top of any other window. But it seems z-index isn't working. This is my menu:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
    .Name("menu").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "z-index: 50;"})
    .Items(items =>
    {
```

And this is my DOM:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, see [example](http://jsbin.com/pibasisuwe/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "position: relative; z-index: 11000" })
)
```

Comment: Vash, it seems we're going to do this project together! :) It doesn't work for me, maybe because my window and menu both have one parent?

Comment: :D You also increased the z-index? When testing it myself it didn't work until 11000. Maybe you need to go even higher?

Comment: Increasing the z-index did the trick. `@style = "position:relative; z-index: 5000000000;"`

Answer (score 1):

z-index only works on positioned elements. You have to make sure your element has one of the following explicitly declared:

- `position:absolute`
- `position:relative`
- `position:fixed`

to allow of z-index to be enabled.

Comment: Well, any of those ruined my menu but didn't fix the issue!  `@style = "position: fixed; z-index: 50;"` Isn't there a better way for kendo menu?

Comment: You will have to provide more information for me to be able to help When providing a position you will normally give a left,top,bottom and/or right values too. It would be helpful to provide a jsfiddle so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: Thanks jonhurlock, I'm using MVC wrappers and they produce the DOM. Increasing z-index did the trick.